# ¿Por Qué el sprite no responde al código?

Tags: unity

estoy creando las mecánicas principales de un juego y en ellas está que aparezca un signo de exclamación, el problema es que el sprite no reacciona a la script, y Unity menciona que no tiene ningún error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo que también intente era usar Triggers, pero igual no funciono.

Comment: no es simplemente porque en lugar de enabled =  false debe ser enabled = true?

Comment: Asegúrate también de que el Order in Layer sea mayor sino aparecerá por detrás del escenario y no se verá.

Comment: Por lo que veo el problema no es que no detecte la colisión, sino que no recibís la notificación de tal colisión, estás usando el método OnCollisionEnter(), pero al ser un juego 2D, deberías usal el método OnCollisionEnter2D()

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que deberias cambiar:

1. No es compatible detectar colisiones entre objetos 2D (BoxCollider2D) y 3D (BoxCollider) ya que uno usa Physics2D y otro Physics3D. Pongamos que usas el 2D ya que parece un plataforma 2D, deberias cambiar el collider de "Cambio de escena" a BoxCollider2D (da igual que sea un cubo 3D).
2. Para que se detecte colision entre 2 objetos, uno de ellos debe tener un RigidBody2D. Ponselo a la Exclamacion y como no querrás que le afecten las fisicas, en la propiedad "Body Type" selecciona **Kinematic**.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. En tu script usa OnTriggerEnter2D ya que OnCollisionEnter2D solo funciona si uno de los 2 objetos tiene un Rigid Body no kinematico (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html)
4. Activa el sprite en vez de apagarlo

   ```
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
   {
       if (collision.transform.tag == "Door")
           sprite.enabled = true;
   }
   ```